# group_by() and summarise() with all combinations (including non-existing combinations)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

Basically, I want to have all unique combinations of column `i` and `j`; and expecting `NA` in column `k` if it is not available (similar like doing a `group_by` & `summarise`, but with all unique possible combinations).

Is there any existing function from the `tidyverse` or else that does the same thing as the one that I wrote below?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
 i = c("a", "a", "b"),
 j = c("x", "y", "x"),
 k = c(100, 300, 20)
)

# I often write this chunk below after group_by & summarise
df %>%
  spread(j, k) %>%
  gather(j, k, -i)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `complete` function from the `tidyverse`
http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html

```
df %>% complete(i,j)
```

This gives you all the combinations of column i, and j

Answer (score 3):

As it seems that `cross_join()` is still a [`tidyverse` feature request on github](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2924), `expand.grid(unique(df$i), unique(df$j), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`  needs to be used to create a data.frame with all unique possible combinations:

```
df %>% 
  right_join(expand.grid(unique(df$i), unique(df$j), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
           by = c("i" = "Var1", "j" = "Var2"))
```

> ```
>   i j   k
> 1 a x 100
> 2 b x  20
> 3 a y 300
> 4 b y  NA
> ```

So, OP's approach using `spread()` and `gather()` appears to be more concise.

Personally, I do prefer the `CJ()` function from the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[CJ(i = i, j = j, unique = TRUE), on = .(i, j)]
```

> ```
>    i j   k
> 1: a x 100
> 2: a y 300
> 3: b x  20
> 4: b y  NA
> ```

`CJ()`can be used as replacement for `expand.grid()` together with `right_join()`:

```
df %>% 
  right_join(data.table::CJ(i = .$i, j = .$j, unique = TRUE))
```

> ```
>   i j   k
> 1 a x 100
> 2 a y 300
> 3 b x  20
> 4 b y  NA
> ```